# Radiobuttons ng-checked not displaying div by default and works only onclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-init, angularjs-ng-checked

I'm new to web development with Angular js. I'm trying to show and hide a textbox inside a div using class. I have two radio buttons **"Yes"** and **"No"**. So, I'm trying to show the div containing the textbox when I click on Yes and hide when I click on No.
Now, I'm trying to do this using ng-class and ng-model only and not using ng-show/ng-hide.

When I keep a radiobutton clicked by default (say Yes) using ng-checked="true", why is the div not displayed and only gets displayed onclick of the button again. Doesn't the ng-checked work for ng-class.
 [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10xd2gpz/1/)

```
<label class="ui-radio checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio" name="toggle1" data-check="1" value="Yes" ng-model="request_same" /> <span> Yes </span> </label>
<label class="ui-radio checkbox-inline"> <input type="radio" ng-Checked="true" name="toggle1" data-check="2" value="No" ng-model="request_same" /> <span> No </span> </label>
```

Comment: you attached fiddle is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `ng-check` it will only select a radio box but, it will not update the ng-model value. Instead of doing ng-checked use `ng-init` and set the value of model.

**Working HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div class="radioToggle1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group" id="request_same" ng-init="request_same='Yes'" >
        <p>Yes or no</p>
        <label class="ui-radio checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="toggle1" data-check="1" value="Yes" ng-model="request_same" /> <span> Yes </span> 
        </label>
        <label class="ui-radio checkbox-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="toggle1" data-check="2" value="No" ng-model="request_same" /> <span> No </span> 
        </label>
    </div>
    <div data-show="1" ng-class="{ active : request_same == 'Yes' }" class="hide-div">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 borderTop">            
            <h5> <strong> Vendor Details </strong> </h5>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-show="2"></div>
</div>
```

Just added `hide-div` class to by default hide the div. And after that `ng-class`will decide to show element or not on basis of condition.

[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/12347/)

Hope this may help you. Thanks.